# Linkages of Blocks in Hyperledger Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In case of Bitcoin Blockchain blocks are linked with hash of previous block. How blocks are linked in the Hyperledger Fabric blockchain? And how to visualize them?

Answer (score 1):

You can find how block in structured in Hyperledger Fabric, by inspecting protobuf definitions, [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/protos/common/common.proto). Where block defined as:

```
message Block {
    BlockHeader header = 1;
    BlockData data = 2;
    BlockMetadata metadata = 3;
}
```

and you will drill down further to definition of `BlockHeader`:

```
message BlockHeader {
    uint64 number = 1; // The position in the blockchain
    bytes previous_hash = 2; // The hash of the previous block header
    bytes data_hash = 3; // The hash of the BlockData, by MerkleTree
}
```

you will see that blocks in Hyperledger Fabric are chained with hashes in very similar fashion to Bitcoin and many other blockchain solutions. The hash (H) of the block N computed by following scheme:

```
H(H) = hash([transactions] || H(N-1) || N)
```

E.g. content of the block, previous block hash and the block sequence number.

Many aspects have good coverage in "[Getting Started](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)" documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [IBM Bluemix](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain/) here is simple tutorial with GO

```
# Create the parent directories on your GOPATH
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger

# Clone the appropriate release codebase into $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
# Note that the v0.5 release is a branch of the repository.  It is defined below after the -b argument
git clone -b v0.5-developer-preview https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric.git
```

If you are installing [IBM BLUEMIX v0.6 release](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/blob/master/docs/setup.md), use this for your git clone command:

```
# The v0.6 release exists as a branch inside the Gerrit fabric repository
git clone -b v0.6 http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric
```

If the fabric is not installed properly on your GOPATH, you will see errors like the one below when building your chaincode

Apart from you can simply refer documentation for linking process!